# Insert output from a PHP file to a div

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a PHP file called `data.php` and I want to use `jQuery` to call the file and return its contents to

```
<div id="datacontainer"></div>
```

every 60 seconds. I have found lots of examples on here where the event is triggered onclick but I am struggling to find a solution for a timed event.

What is the best practice way to insert the output of a file named `path/to/file/data.php` into a div using `jQuery/Ajax`?

Comment: Use what you've seen from the examples + `setInterval()`

Comment: Have you tried any codes already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/* set interval to call function every 60 seconds */
setInterval(function(){
/* start ajax */
    $.ajax({
    url: "path/to/file/data.php",
    type: "GET"

    }).done(function(html) {
    /* when it's done, take the return and replace whatever is in the DIV with it 
    if you dont want to replace, but append, just use the .append(html) function */
    $( '#datacontainer' ).html( html );

    });
}
/*60 seconds * 1000 miliseconds*/
,60000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: http://api.jquery.com/load/ and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval

Example:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $( "#datacontainer" ).load( "data.php" );
}, 60000);
```

Also consider using `successCallback` of `jQuery load` and `setTimeout`, as usually you want to wait till server will return contents. In my opinion best practice would be:

```
var ID = null,
    time = 60000,
    func = function() {
    $( "#datacontainer" ).load( "data.php", function() {
        ID = setTimeout(func, time);
    });
};
ID = setTimeout(func, time);
```

But it depends on use case.

Answer (score 0):

```
var $contentdiv = jQuery('#datacontainer');
window.setInterval(function () {
  $contentdiv.load("path/to/file/data.php");
}, 60000);
```

If you had googled "timer events javascript" you would have found this [MDN page...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Timers)